# JavaScript RegExp replace strings

Tags: javascript, regex

How to search and replace all words "Hello" and "hello" in string "**Hello**, lorem ipsum **hello** and p**hello**derm" with exception substring in "phelloderm"

Comment: Could be done with word-boundary characters. Look this up.

Comment: What code you have written so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @AlexShesterov: not _quite_ a duplicate of this one. Only partially. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b`

```
"Hello, lorem ipsum hello and phelloderm".replace( /\bhello\b/gi, "$1" )
```

outputs

> "$1, lorem ipsum $1 and phelloderm"